# monitoring sql connection info with java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection, monitoring

UPDATE: I solved this problem exactly the same way friends suggested. But I kind of missed the fact that I have to follow mysql's protocol in order to get the result. In mysql there is always an initial handshaking packets doesn't have any data field so you don't get any data with getInputStream. The only way is to create a mysql connection in your own server and send the result to your client. It works very well. Thank you everybody

I want to read mysql connection info with java. For example I made a server socket with java on port 4444. Then I made a jdbc connection on port 4444. But it doesn't work. I don't know why and even I don't know if it is possible or not. 
This is the sever code:

```
int portNr = 4444;
// Create a ServerSocket object to watch that port for clients
ServerSocket ss;
try {
    ss = new ServerSocket(portNr);

    System.out.println("starting...");

    // Here we loop indefinitely, just waiting for clients to connect
    while (true) {

        // accept() does not return until a client requests a connection
        // Now that a client has arrived, create an instance of our
        // special
        // thread subclass to respond to it.
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = ss.accept();

            System.err.println("heheh"+clientSocket);
            // PrintWriter out = new
            // PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                  new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine = in.readLine();
            System.err.println(inputLine)....;</i>
```

It prints "hehehe"; but it doesn't print input line.

And this is my connection code:

```
public class messagetest
{
    // The JDBC Connector Class.
    private static final String dbClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

    private static final String CONNECTION =
                      "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:4444/shadi";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws
                         Exception,SQLException
     {
        System.out.println(dbClassName);

        Class.forName(dbClassName);

        // Properties for user and password. Here the user and password are both 'paulr'
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.put("user","--------");
        p.put("password","-------");

        System.err.println("after p");
        Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION,p);

        System.err.println("client:");
```

It doesn't print "client:"
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Would like to retrieve DB information like Tables, Column, Data type and constraint, etc....?

Comment: do you want to see what the jdbc driver tries to send to the db to establish connection?

Comment: exactly. I want to see what queries are sent to my DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot bind your own Server on the same port as the DB-Server instance.

If you really want to "monitor" it like that, use a little "man in the middle": Set the DB to another port, say 4445. Then inside your monitor listen on 4444, that clients will connect to and make your own connection to 4445. Then forward input and output between the two.

EDIT:
OK, we cleared that up. Forget about the first part of my answer.

Your server runs on 4444 and your db on 3306.

So in your monitor, you'll need two connections: One Monitor-Client and one Monitor-DB.
You'll have to have two threads reading on each of them and writing what it has read to the other.

And I don't know if you will be happy using readLine. For checking out what is being sent, I recommend reading bytes ...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I did that. 4444 is a port that is different than my DB port.

Comment: "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:4444/shadi" Then this is not your connection string?

Comment: this is the way I connect to my own server. I mean I want to monitor commands the way that the one who wants the connection doesn't know and doesn't need to change its code exactly like proxy

Comment: But in the code above, you have that mysql server running on the same machine you run your code (127.0.0.1) on port 4444 and insinde your code you are trying to bind your serversocket on 4444. So it is the same port on the same machine isn't it? Or do I miss something here? So if you change your db's port you'll be able to receive and send to clients. You'll have to read from the client and write that to your db-connection and vice versa. And so you can sniff on what is going through. Clients won't have to change their code.

Comment: if the port of my db was 4444 I couldn't run my server. right? client is connecting to port 4444 but the port 4444 is not db. it's my server. db port is 3306.

Comment: Ok, that sounds better. Just to clarify this: Do you want to emulate a jdbc driver so your clients use the connectionstring "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:4444/shadi" and end up in your monitor?

Comment: I'm so stupid, sorry. For some reason I thought you were using that connection string in the server ... I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Don't worry :) but there is something!! even when I use readbyte I can't get anything. I think that the "DriverManager.getConnection" only open a socket and it doesn't send any data. see my code prints "hehehe" but it doesn't read from inputstream

Comment: Possible. Maybe try to make a query?